# Interpreting a group of symmetries with or without restrictions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

f an m are two 1d vectors, they should not be towards each other <- <-(initial), -> ->, <- -> and unallowed f case -> <-. We define rotations of these vectors(or just change the arrow directions) from initial state by $f$ and $m$.
(I know this is simply an "implication" but i want to try it with group theory.)

Edit: Vector context is added.

For the following group of symmetries, $f$ is not allowed;

$$D=\{e,m,m^2,fm,mf^2m | m^2=mf^2m=e\} f \notin D$$
Actually, i know D is not a group because it is not closed under multiplication.

But i like to know if following is a correct interpretation when there is not mathematical rigor? And also would factoring out terms always help?

1. For $f$ element restricted case, when we factor a calculation into the allowed elements, we will encounter any calculations that have $f$ **internally** and cancel the calculation with invalid result which is what we desire.

   $$mffm^2f=(mf^2m)(m)(f)$$ - Single $f$ not allowed, invalid result.
2. For $f$ element allowed case, we define it as a group complying with
   the rules then we have

   $$D=\{m, f | m^2=f^2=e\} f \in D$$

   But in this case there could be $f$ **internally** which will make
   any calculation useless as we might be breaking our restriction.

   Check following, result is $e$ which is valid for us but it contains $f$ internally which
   we do not want; $$f^2m^2=ee=e$$

Comment: I don't think it is clear what it is you are looking for. If you consider invalid any result containing a singleton $f$, and you allow associativity between products of $m$ and $f$, then any expression you have containing $f$ or any of its products is invalid, so you might as well not include those elements in your set, at which point you have $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: In the first definition of $D$, you require $m^2 = e$, but you seem to have $e$ and $m^2$ in $D$. Could you clarify?

Comment: Actually, $m^2$ and $mf^2m$ are excessive there.$m^2$ could be removed but $mf^2m$ is used for removal from calculations.